Cover change menu does not appear in SCP
I want to run a cover change analysis in SCP. Unfortunately, the Cover change menu does not appear among Post-processing tools. How do I solve this?

Have you installed the plugin for Semi-Automatic Classification?

Yes, the plugin is installed

The NIWA-plugin has one button in the toolbars, and is accessible via the plugin-menu. The other plugin by Luca Congedo comes with its own toolbar.

Thanks for your assistance. Currently, I'm using the SCP by Luca Congedo and the Cover change is not available in the SCP toolbar menu.

It would have been very helpful, if you had clearly stated the exact plugin, and the exact issue within the plugin from the beginning. Beside that, did you get into contact with the plugin provider?
